# Can't load Ionic project from mobile phone

Tags: javascript, angular, windows, ionic-framework, xampp

I have a problem with my Ionic project. When I run ionic serve command from the project directory, it starts normally, but when I want to load the page on my phone, I can´t access it. Project is running on localhost on my PC and when I type the IP address with the port 8100, it can´t load. (192.168.1.50:8100). Before Windows update 1903 it worked just fine... 
Also, I tried to run xampp server (port 80) and it worked even on phone.

Thanks for your advices.

Comment: Hi, is your Phone and PC on the same network?

Comment: Have you tried Ionic `DevApp`. download it from playstore and run your project directly on your phone.

Comment: @Bundayy Olayinka  Yes, I am on the same network...

Comment: @Najam us Saqib, Yes, and it doesn´t work aswell.

Comment: SOLVED: I put behind ionic serve --address=ip_of_my_computer and it worked.

Comment: are you connected to same Wifi? your laptop and Mobile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED: I ran command "ionic serve --address=ip_of_computer" and it worked.